# How to make 2 website communicate with each other hosted on different cloud server

Tags: php, rest, api, server, cloud

I have one website with one database hosted on Alibaba cloud chinese platform, I want to make a clone of the same website, host it on Alibaba cloud international platform with another database, now my question is how can I make those 2 websites communicate with each other so that I can keep datas in both the databases synced.
I am aware that having 2 domains but hosting on one server will solve my problem, but that is not to be done.

Comment: You may want to look at this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/65354

Comment: actually I have 2 different websites running individually but some how want them both to communicate with each other, not finding any solution . Does rest api will be considered  here to do so?

Comment: If you are happy to sync them using rest api every N minute then you are good to go , but you may consider the solutions on the above link as well ?

Comment: yes but that will take a server load correct?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is you cannot in the manner that you have asked it.

The problem is that you cannot reliably communicate with a server inside China from outside China without setting up a VPN. This is expensive and requires government approval. If you try to get around this you will find extremely slow transfer speeds and / or blocking of your communications.

1) To connect a server inside China to a server outside of China, you will need to setup a VPN.

2) You will need to register the VPN used to transport traffic from China to outside China.

3) Currently, VPNs are only allowed to transfer traffic back to a company's corporate office.

In summary you will need to treat servers inside China as completely separate from servers in the rest of the world. Unless you have the budget, ICP license and government approval, synchronization between servers or databases will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the LAMP Stack, If so then you can access the MySQL instance create a new database with the same data but changing fields like WP_HOME & WP_SITEURL and access it via a VPC in other instance on AlibabaCloud adding custom security rules. You can bind this database in the new website.

I never tried it but you have to look into config.php/wp_config.php to set these parameters.

Let me know if you need more information.